# Problema na configuração do DataSource com Postgres!

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

Estou tentando configurar meu DataSource para criar uma API REST, o mesmo nao esta funcionando quando uso o PostgreSQL, mas se usar o Oracle DB funciona normalmente. Gostaria de usar o PostgreSQL, alguém sabe me dizer o porque do erro, o que estou fazendo de errado?
Eu tenho a seguinte configuração de aplicativo para Spring Data.

```
package br.com.controle.empresarial;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DAOConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("br.com.controle.empresarial");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

pom.xml
[image: pom.xml]

Erro
[image: Erro]

Link project -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5tkhnQsK26nlmucFqKjNvaXXAYYbx1Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Olá, poste o código na pergunta e não o print. Isso não ajuda na visualização e também não permite copiar o código para um eventual teste.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione isso no arquivo application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261146/5360385)

Comment: tentei colocar isso já, não funcionou.